# What the Differences between prctl(PR_SET_NAME PR_SET_NAME ) and pthread_setname_np()?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I need to set name for some threads.

What are the fifferences between `prctl(PR_SET_NAME PR_SET_NAME )` and `pthread_setname_np()`?

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_setname_np(pthread_t pth, char* th_name)` sets the thread `pth`'s name to `th_name`, whereas `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, th_name)` will set the *calling* thread's name to be `th_name`.

In the case that the thread passed to `pthread_setname_np()` is actually the calling thread, it will simply call `prctl()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that when the thread name is longer than 16 bytes (including NULL terminator), `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ...)` will truncate the string for you.  Where as `pthread_setname_np()` will simply fail returning ERANGE error code.

Therefore when switching from prctl to pthread_setname_np, you might want to first truncate the name beforehand.  Example below.

```
const std::string threadName16 = threadName.substr(0, 15);
pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), threadName16.c_str());
```